# Applying Constraints Programmatically to UIImageView Subview

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, constraints, nslayoutconstraint

1. I have a `uiview` that resizes with `autolayout` constraints.
2. I have a `uiimageview` that I insert as a `subview` and then store, in a database, the distances from the leading/trailing/top/bottom edges to the `uiview` superview. *Another note is the original `uiimageview` can be transformed and translated so `CGPoint`, `CGAffineTransform`, and `CGRect` are saved as well.*
3. I fetch from the database these "constant" values for each edge and then programmatically activate the constraints to an instantiated `uiimageview` to replicate the original `uiimageview` inserted.

My reason to add constraints is for the `uiimageview` to adapt proportionately to a change in the `uiview` size.

My issue is there's something wacky with my code that I cannot resolve on why I can't reproduce the original `uiimageview` based on the data I had stored, fetched, and then reapplied.

I'm admittedly lost when it comes to using constraints programmatically and any help would be appreciated.

```
//Storing constraint constants of original uiimageview in original container uiview
let leadingConstraint = originalImageView.frame.minX
let trailingConstraint = oldContainer.frame.maxX - originalImageView.frame.maxX
let topConstraint = originalImageView.frame.minY
let bottomConstraint = oldContainer.frame.maxY - originalImageView.frame.maxY

//Fetching and applying constants to new uiimageview in new container uiview (Separate operation from the above! Above takes place first!)

newImageView.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 80, height: 80)
newImageView.center = CGPoint(x: saved.x, y: saved.y)
newImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(a: saved.a, b: saved.b, c: saved.c, d: saved.d, tx: saved.tx, ty: gifForm.ty)

newContainer.insertSubview(newImageView, at: 0)

newImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
let leadingConstraint = newImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: newContainer.leadingAnchor, constant: saved.leadingConstant)
let trailingConstraint = newImageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: newContainer.trailingAnchor, constant: -saved.trailingConstant)
let topConstraint = newImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: newContainer.topAnchor, constant: saved.topConstant)
let bottomConstraint = newImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: newContainer.bottomAnchor, constant: -saved.bottomConstant)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([leadingConstraint, trailingConstraint, topConstraint, bottomConstraint])
```

Comment: may be playing with transform destroys constraints logic so all calculations will be not accurate

Comment: @Sh_Khan yeah i commented out transform and it is much closer to the original...but i do need the transform due to account for rotation or flipping an image horizontally..is there any way to override or use them in a way that cooperates?

Answer (score 0):

Try exclusively using either constraints (setting `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false`) or not (leaving it `true`).

You can't use both, meaning you can't use things like `.center` if you are planning to use constraints, but instead have to use the counterparts like `centerXAnchor` and `centerYAnchor`.

Also not sure if this is just negligence, but the four lines at the end use the same property names as above.

Comment: Yeah noticing that, that's the issue where setting transform is conflicting with the constraints..is there any way to use them in parallel? i need to use transform to apply things like rotation to the image but also want to use constraints so it scales proportional to the superview. @Sean C. Li

Comment: @Chris Try switching over to constraints completely using a constraint to directly relate `heightAnchor` to `widthAnchor` to imitate `transform`. If it results in weird proportions, you can also adjust the image view's `contentMode` to `aspectFill`. On the other hand, you can use the other method exclusively, which is honestly easier IMO to implement and animate if needed, but I do prefer constraints.